# What does the text within the curly brackets (and the vertical lines within them) represent?

Tags: html, template-engine

See below:

```
<p
style="margin: 0px; text-align: left; color: #666666; line-height: 25px; 
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
&bull; {|FeatureFour|}</p>
```

So the above, is a standard paragraph tag but with the extra text (which seems like some sort of variable);

The code is from a random markup file I came across, I am curius to see what it represents.

Comment: From the html point of view it's just text. However it could be that some framework is used that replaces the text with some data, but you can't tell that for sure by just looking at the html.

Comment: Usually it's some HTML templateing engine that uses that kind of markup

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I was thinking too that it could be some framework or package that looks at the HTML and dynamically inserts certain content within it

Answer (score 1):

`&bull` gives you to use a bullet mark and the **{|FeatureFour|}** is the content inside the `<p>` tag, so **{|FeatureFour|}** is just a paragraph content

```html
<p
style="margin: 0px; text-align: left; color: #666666; line-height: 25px; 
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
&bull; {|FeatureFour|}</p>
```

```html
<p
style="margin: 0px; text-align: left; color: #666666; line-height: 25px; 
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
&bull; {|FeatureFour|}</p>

<p
style="margin: 0px; text-align: left; color: #666666; line-height: 25px; 
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
&bull; Hello world!</p>
```

. You can change these content in the text editor.